# mixing pattern and exact matches in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to search for different things in a string. For example, I am ready a file and parsing it all the way through. Then I match few strings in each line. The String in question could be a pattern match or exact match, how can I accomplish it in a single statement?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
set $string = " My name is Peter Gabriel Perlston and I live in Gabriel_Perlston town"

set match [regexp -all -inline {Pet|"Perlston"} $string]
```

Now what I want is that every time it matches a pattern Pet, it prints something OR if it matches Perlston exactly with nothing around like _..Just that word..it print something.

I can do it in multiple statements but I was hoping if there is a one liner that I can use? I want to make this a generic statement so in future if there is another string or exact name, I can add to $string and be done with it.

Comment: You example is not valid Tcl. You may also want to properly format it?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to use a regex with alternatives with the `|` character.

In the below code, the `Pet` will find any match of Pet anywhere, and `\mPerlston\M` uses the word boundary start and end markers before and after Perlson.

`set match [regexp -all -inline {Pet|\mPerlston\M} $string]`

Comment: @Public, Tcl regular expressions are documented in [`re_syntax`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)